# Making two players move one with wasd and one with arrow keys

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a smash bros like game and am new to coding; trying to learn how to have two different controls for two different players

Here is my Code:

````
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float gravity;
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundlayer;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask platformlayer;
    private Rigidbody2D body;
    //created reference to Rigidbody2D to unity
    private Animator anim;
    private BoxCollider2D boxcollider;
    private void Awake() //awake is calles when script is being loaded
    {
        //grab references for rigidbody and animator from object
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        boxcollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        //check the player object and the get component method will check the player object for a omponent of type RB2D - stores it inside body component
    }


    private void Update()//called on every frame
    {
        
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * speed, body.velocity.y);//moves the body left and right

        //flip player when moving left/right
        if (horizontalInput > 0.01f)
            transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        else if (horizontalInput < -0.01f)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);


        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded())
            Jump();```
````

Answer (score 0):

Make two `KeyCode` variables at the beginning of the script:

```cs
[SerializeField] private KeyCode leftButton;
[SerializeField] private KeyCode rightButton;
```

Create a new `Vector2` for the velocity.

```cs
Vector2 velocity;
```

Update the values of the `velocity` based on the KeyCodes.

```cs
if (Input.GetKey(leftButton)) {
    velocity.x = 1 * speed;
}
else if (Input.GetKey(rightButton)) {
    velocity.x = -1 * speed;
}
else {
    velocity.x = 0;
}
```

Then update the `body` velocity.

```cs
body.velocity = new Vector2(velocity.x, body.velocity.y);
```